# Difference between %type and datatype in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

which is better in the performance in oracle

```
declare
debit credit%TYPE; 
begin
....
end;

or

declare
debit number(10,2);
begin
...
end;
```

will the first block refer to the table to get the datatype on every execution or it is done once.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference.  Both references are resolved at compile time.  An anchored type probably takes very slightly more time to resolve at compile time but it is unlikely that you care particularly about compilation performance and it is unlikely that you'd be able to measure the time required to do that lookup.

The difference is that in the first case, your block will be recompiled when someone modifies the data type of the column (your anchored type would have to be `table.column%type` so your block isn't actually valid).  In the second case, when someone modifies the data type of the underlying column, they have to comb through every piece of code that queries the table to make the same change.  Using anchored types is, therefore, much more sustainable.

Comment: Completely agreed - with one side comment. "Performance" in 99.9% of cases means runtime, but sometimes we are also interested in compilation time. table.column%type will be very slightly slower to COMPILE, but there is no difference in runtime performance - and the benefits of anchored type make it very much worth the price.

Comment: But as described perfectly by Justin. Anchored datatype is always preferred to reduce the code re work if any datatype change takes place.